# making a game of hangman, what code will check if a character is a certain character

Tags: java, class, loops, methods

so far i have enough to get the word and this is where im stuck at

```
System.out.println("Word: " + secretWord.getWordMask());   
    //System.out.println("Guesses: " + guesses);
    System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String guess = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println(guess);
    if ()
```

so i have it to the point where the user enters the guess, but then it needs to be something like, if guess is a character in the words, then reveal the character

Comment: Write a loop to check the entered letter is there in the masked word. because there may b chance of same letter coming more than once in a same word.

Answer (score 0):

```
guess.chatAt(index);
```

This will get you the character at the given index in the string which was entered. You can loop through the string using this, and whenever a `match` character is found, reveal it.

This is how you can use it:-

```
Character ch = guess.charAt(0);
if(word.contains(ch.toString())){
    //Reveal the character.
}
```

Comment: the thing is, the word is random, so i dont even know what it is

Comment: check the edit. It'll check if the guess is present in the word or not, and if it is, you can reveal that particular character.